# Unable to log addition Info using LogContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am logging error using serilog.log.error in catch block. I want to log DBName and Client name as well.

Here is my code:

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System.Web.Http;
using IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Serilog;
using CincAccounting.Areas.Common.Utils;
using CincAccounting.Middleware;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(CincAccounting.Startup))]

namespace CincAccounting
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var output = "{DBName} {Client} {Exception}";

            // Configure logger
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .WriteTo.File(System.IO.Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "logs\\accounting\\CINC-Accounting.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,outputTemplate: output)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .CreateLogger();

            Log.Information("Application Started...");
            app.Use<LoggingEnrichmentMiddleware>(Log.Logger);
            //app.Use<SerilogMiddleware>();            
        }
    }
}
```

LoggingEnrichmentMiddleware.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using CincAccounting.Areas.Common.MultiTenant;
using CincAccounting.Areas.Common.Utils;
using CincAccounting.Areas.UsersManagement.Models;
using CincAccounting.Controllers;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Context;
using System.Web.Http;
namespace CincAccounting.Middleware
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class LoggingEnrichmentMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
    {
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="next"></param>
        /// <param name="logger"></param>

        public LoggingEnrichmentMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, ILogger logger)
       : base(next)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
        {
            string txtDBName = "";
            string txtUserName = "";
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session!=null && HttpContext.Current.Session[GlobalConstants.TenantKey] != null)
            {
                ITenant tanent = (ITenant)HttpContext.Current.Session[GlobalConstants.TenantKey];
                if (tanent != null)
                {
                    txtDBName = tanent.DbName;
                }
            }
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session!=null && HttpContext.Current.Session[GlobalConstants.UserProfileCinc] != null)
            {
                UserProfileCINC userProfile = (UserProfileCINC)HttpContext.Current.Session[GlobalConstants.UserProfileCinc];
                if (userProfile != null)
                {
                    txtUserName = userProfile.txtUserName;
                }
            }

            
            // enrich LogContext with user info
            using (LogContext.PushProperty("DBName", txtDBName))
            using (LogContext.PushProperty("Client", txtUserName))
            { 
                try
                {
                   // this.logger.Information("UserName : " + context.Authentication.User.Identity.Name);
                    await this.Next.Invoke(context);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {    
               this.logger.Error(ex, $"{nameof(LoggingEnrichmentMiddleware)} caught exception.");
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am logging error from controller catch block serilog.log.error("error message").

I am unable to see DBName and Client with logged error.

Please suggest me what is missing.

Comment: You seem to forget to record them. For more detailed operations, please refer to this article:https://benfoster.io/blog/serilog-best-practices/

Answer (score 0):

I see no `serilog.log.error`, only `this.logger.Error`.
You ask why you dont see DbName and Client in log, if I read you correctly. It is because you don't log it. You log the exception, which can be anything, and the name of the method.

Maybe something like `this.logger.Error(ex, $"{nameof(LoggingEnrichmentMiddleware)} caught exception. DBName={txtDBName},UserName={txtUserName}");

Comment: I am calling serilog.log.logger.error from other controller methods. For Example: public ActionResult ChartList()
        {
            try
            {               
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {               
                Serilog.Log.Logger.Error("Error: ChartListController.ChartList: " + e.Message);                
            }
        }